# Printing odd numbers between two numbers

Tags: assembly, mips

I need to print odd numbers between num1 and num2, the code I have come up with so far prints all the numbers. I have been struggling to make it just print the odd numbers.

```
addi $v0, $zero, 4    
la $a0, str.displaynum    
syscall

add $s0,$zero, $t0 #starting number / loop counter   
loop:

addi $v0, $zero, 1     
add $a0,  $zero, $s0    
syscall


addi $a0,$zero,','     
addi $v0,$zero, 11    
syscall    

addi $s0,$s0,1 #add one to loop count    
ble $s0, $t1, loop #end loop if number is equal to end number
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which programming language you are using, I can't tell from seeing, but what you want it something with Modulu. It is represented in most programs using a % sign. Num1 % Num2 would be the same as returning the remainder of dividing num1 by num2. For example 5 % 2 is 1, since 5/2 is 2 with a remainder of 1. So what you would use would be an if statement.

```
if(number%2==0) then number is even; else number is odd;
```

You would have it print out the number in the else clause for odd.

You can also make a loop.

```
while(number>1) do number=number-2; done;
if(number==0) then number is even; else number is odd;
```

Comment: [this will help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695333/how-do-i-correctly-use-the-mod-operator-in-mips) if you still had the question.